# How to create 9-patch images in gimp?

Tags: gimp, png, plugin

I would like to create [nine-patch images](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) for mobile and web. How can I do this in Gimp? Is there any plugin for creating nine-patch images in Gimp ?

Comment: You should provide a specification for those images. And tell us what you have tried already, if anything.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: AFAIK 9.png images are just plain PNGs with an outer 1-pixel border which isn't displayed but gives clues about the parts that can be replicated/stretched to resize the image. From that point of view Gimp has everything you need (use the pencil with a 1x1 brush to put the marks in the borders). Of course you won't get a live feedback on how the image will behave with the current marks.

Comment: Related question: [How to create nine-patch and use it in my App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793099/how-to-create-nine-patch-and-use-it-in-my-app)

Comment: I don't see the problem (given the linked documentation). Draw your image, increase the canvas by 1 pixel on each side, and draw a black line (using the pencil tool) to define the patch sizes.