# Inkscape 9-patch image export or plugin?

Tags: inkscape, export, png

I have some artwork made in Inkscape, which I would like to export as a 9-patch image (info [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/17FEOZPub7-rsGlWrEFjhBk1pF_3Ywz0mMmhIewkJi_Y/present?slide=id.i0)). Does anyone know how I would go about doing this? If this functionality isn't supported *out of the box*, is there any plugin that might achieve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to elaborate what you consider a 9 patch image.

Answer (score 1):

Related questions and documentations:
[How to create 9-patch images in gimp?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77891/how-to-create-9-patch-images-in-gimp#comment120419_77891)
[How to create nine-patch and use it in my App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793099/how-to-create-nine-patch-and-use-it-in-my-app)
[Android 9-patch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

9-patch images are not a real file format but only a convention. Export your image as a png and you are done, assuming that you already drew the 1px border around the actual image. If you want you can rename your file `image.png` to `image.9.png` to emphasize, that the image is used as a 9-patch.

If you just have the actual image, expand the canvas by 1px on each side and draw a black 1px wide rectangle on the top and left border. The black lines define the stretchable area.